# Get parallax on ListView Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, parallax

I'm new to Xamarin and C#.

I'm making an app with a ListView. Therefore I want to add a settings section where to can specify your search.

I want it to be like above the ListView as header and with the effect that when you scroll down the ListView the section gets smaller. I googled and found something called parallax effect and found a nuget package called [DevsDNA.XFParallax](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DevsDNA.XFParallax/).

Can I use this for ListViews, too? And is this the way you should do this? Or is there a better way of handle such things?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Header` of listview .

```
 <ListView x:Name="GroupedView"
         GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Title}"
         GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding ShortName}"
         IsGroupingEnabled="true">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

          // ...

        </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>  

     <!-- Group Header Customization-->
     <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

           //  set the layout of header here

         </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>          
</ListView>
```